# i have a problem with ajax When the data is returned

Tags: php, jquery, json, ajax

I get the following error when I send information to the server and try to find it in json:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected token in SON at position 0

jq is:

```
$.ajaxSetup({
            dataType:"json",
        });
        $.ajax({
            url:'search/follow',
            method:'POST',
            data:{'username':username},
            success:function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                console.clear();
                console.log(data);
            },
            error:function (data,textStatus,jqXHR) {
                alert(jqXHR);
            },
            complete:function (jqXHR,textStatus) {

            }
        });
```

php is :

```
$result=$this->model->follow($_POST,$username);
   echo json_encode($result);
```

Comment: What is being sent from the server to the browser? This is the crucial information.

Answer (score 0):

Two possible reasons:

- your $result is probably NULL indicating error in follow() method so json_encode will generate error message
- there is error message echoed before echoing content (PHP warning or 
  notice)

Enable browser console (Ctrl+Shift+K) and watch, ajax call to your "search/follow" URL will be logged, see what is returned.